# What gets sent to a application when you open a file?

Tags: java, file, event-handling, operating-system

So, my question is simple (And I am not smart enough to find the answer)

When you click on a file, like `blahblahblah.txt`. Since your default text editor is `textedit.app` for example, does the computer send the application `blahblahblah.txt`'s file path as a argument.

Sorry, I'm new to working with files.

The reason I am asking this is because, if I package a `.jar` file inside a `.exe` I am confused on how the computer handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different mechanisms will be used, depending on the OS, and what you are actually doing.

When you double-click on a file to open it in (say) an editor, the OS will *typically*:

- Determine the file's type (via its metadata, suffix or some heuristic)
- Lookup the application associated with the file type
- Launch the application, passing the file's pathname as an argument

(The details are OS specific ... but not really relevant to what I think you are really asking about.)

But when you launch a JAR file wrapped in an EXE, then the EXE itself will take care of the JVM launching.  How it does it will depend on how the EXE has been generated; i.e. what 3rd-party tool you used.

Either way, what happens when you run a EXE that wraps a JAR is *likely to be different* to what happens when you (say) double-click on a text file.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly system specific. Generally, what you are describing is a function of the graphical shell in use.

Some systems, e.g. eunuchs, have no concept of file extensions at all. Extensions are simply file naming conventions. Enuchs graphical shells have to parse the file name to find the extension.

Other operating systems have file systems where the file extension or type is encoded separately from the file name.

On Windoze, (which does store file extensions separately) the application mapping is done through the Registry.

On Mac, there is a Launch Services Database that does the mapping. It is much more elaborate than the Windoze system.

At the command line things are entirely different. On Eunuchs command line shells the "extensions" are meaningless.

On other systems, there are default extensions. If you are at the Windoze prompt and type

> program

The command interpreter looks for a "program" with a .com, .bat, or .exe .

On VMS,

> R PROGRAM

causes the command interpreter to look for PROGRAM.EXE and run it. Or

> @file

causse the command interpreter to look for and execute the command file file.com.

Thus you are dealing with two system specific variables:

1. Does the underlying file system support file extensions?
2. How does the shell map file extensions to applications.